# Junit test cases not executing methods inside foreach loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, java-8

This is my method for which I am trying to write test cases:

```
public void performTask() {
        List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList();
        employeeList = employeeRepository.findAll();
        employeeList.stream().filter(list -> list.getAge() != null)
                             .filter(list -> list.getAge() > 20)
                             .forEach(emp -> {
            var employeeFromDb = employeeRepository.findByEmail(emp.getEmail());
            sendMail(employeeFromDb.getEmail());
            employeeFromDb.setWork(null);
            employeeRepository.saveAndFlush(employeeFromDb);
        });

    }
```

Test case:

```
@Test
void testPerformTask(){
Employee emp1 = new Employee();
emp1.setEmail("abc@gmail.com");
emp1.setAge(23);
emp1.setWork("developer");
Employee emp2 = new Employee();
emp2.setEmail("xyz@gmail.com");
emp2.setAge(null);
emp2.setWork("developer");
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList();  
employeeList.add(emp1);
employeeList.add(emp2);
doReturn(employeeList).when(employeeRepository).findAll();
doReturn(emp1).when(employeeRepository).findByEmail("abc@gmail.com");
doReturn(emp1).when(employeeRepository).saveAndFlush(emp1);
employeeService.performTask();
}
```

Junit test is covering till forEach but not covering anything inside forEach loop. Any suggestion would help.

Comment: Could be a bug in findAll.  Could be a bug in your coverage detector.  Could be a bug in Employee where you've marked things static that shouldn't be.  We don't have nearly enough information to tell.  Start by using a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: Debugging is a good idea, you could also improve your performTask method implementation by maybe doing the filters first and in a separate block do the loop on the filters result list